# How to make my methods work together

Tags: java

I'm just a beginner in Java, so I'm trying to write some simple program with graphical interface. The purpose of the program is to count gimatria value of the word that user prints. To do this user have to click on the button. I have no idea how to make my methods work together. I've found a lot of answers concerning method invoking here, but i really don't understand how implement them in my case.
Here the code:

```
public class Gim {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    new Display();

        }
}
```

---

```
public class Display extends JFrame {

private JButton execute;
private JTextArea result;
public JTextField word;

public Display () {

    sendTextArea();
    sendFrame();
    sendButton();

}

public void sendButton() {

    execute = new JButton();
    execute.setBounds(450, 90, 130, 30);
    execute.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(word.getText() != null){


            }
        }
    });
    add(execute);
}

public void sendTextArea() {
    result = new JTextArea();
    word = new JTextField();
    result.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 20);
    word.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 20);
    result.setEditable(false);
    word.setEditable(true);
    word.setFont(new Font( "Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    result.setFont(new Font( "Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    add(result);
    add(word);
}

 private void sendFrame() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(true);
    setSize(800, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

---

```
public class Count  {

public static int myMethod() throws IOException{

        String text;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++){
        char bukv=text.charAt(i);
        switch(bukv){
        case 'א':  sum += 1;
        break;
        case 'ב': sum += 2;
        break;
        case 'ג':  sum += 3;
        break;
        case 'ד':  sum += 4;
        break;
        case 'ה':  sum += 5;
        break;
        case 'ו':  sum += 6;
        break;
        case 'ז':  sum += 7;
        break;
        case 'ח':  sum += 8;
        break;
        case 'ט':  sum += 9;
        break;
        case 'י':  sum += 10;
        break;
        case 'כ':  sum += 20;
        break;
        case 'ל':  sum += 30;
        break;
        case 'מ':  sum += 40;
        break;
        case 'נ':  sum += 50;
        break;
        case 'ס':  sum += 60;
        break;
        case 'ע':  sum += 70;
        break;
        case 'פ':  sum += 80;
        break;
        case 'צ':  sum += 90;
        break;
        case 'ק':  sum += 100;
        break;
        case 'ר':  sum += 200;
        break;
        case 'ש':  sum += 300;
        break;
        case 'ת':  sum += 400;
        break;
            } 
        }
                return sum; 
    }   
 }
```

Comment: Don't you need some field for the result? Anyway, you should call your method for calculation and display of the result from the button's event handler, which right now you basically left empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the ActionListener is an anonymous class that overrides the method ActionPerformed. This is the point in your program that 'captures' userinteraction. Here you will need to invoke the method that counts the gimatria value of the word the user entered.

You can achieve that by invoking the method you wrote: Count.myMethod(). But this won't be enough since your method has no actual word to work with. So you should improve your method by adding a formal parameter: myMethod(String word). Now you can invoke/call it from the ActionPerformed method with an argument: Count.myMethod(word). Since this method yields a result, you will need to catch it: int total = Count.myMethod(word);. This result needs to be displayed in the designated textfield in your GUI: result.setText(String.valueOf(result);

You should get something like:

```
   execute.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(word.getText() != null){
                int res = Count.myMethod(word.getText());
                result.setText(String.valueOf(res));
            }
        }
    });
    add(execute);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
execute.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (word.getText() != null) {
                    try {
                        Count.myMethod();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

instead of this:

```
execute.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (word.getText() != null) {

                }
            }
        });
```

The Button you create to execute has a empty EventHandler. By adding your method to the event Handler it will be executed. the result could be saved with replacing this: `Count.myMethod();` by this: `int i = Count.myMethod();`

You also should add an parameter to `myMethod()` to be able to reach it the text you want to check. You could do this like that:

```
public static int myMethod(String toCompare) throws IOException{
    String text = toCompare;
    ...
```

Calling the method then would work like that:

```
Count.myMethod(yourStringFromUI);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change the Count.myMethod to allow a parameter + Delete the "String text;" statement :

```
public static int myMethod(String paramText) throws IOException{...
```

Call the Count class from the ActionListener of Display and create a method to handle your result :

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(word.getText() != null){
           display(Count.myMethod(word.getText()));
        }
    }

    public void display(int count){
      System.out.println(count);
    }
```